# "an" -> "a" When Describing a Noun With Adjectives

Tags: syntax, language-change, determiners, articles, indefinite-article

Observed in fluent speech:

> a unrounded vowel

To a native English speaker, the following would be expected instead:

> an unrounded vowel

What's happening here?  It looks like the speaker is inserting the adjective inside `a vowel`, and then not transforming `a` into `an`.  It looks like a rule-ordering bug to me.  Is there a name for this particular glitch?

Comment: This might occur naturally in a pragmatic context where *unrounded* is 'detached' from the preceding determiner. For instance, the speaker may have paused to grope for the word (*Here we have a a a ... unrounded vowel*) or the speaker may have wished to give unusual emphasis to the negative (*but over here we have a UNrounded vowel*), in which case a glottal stop would probably intrude, to avoid the awkward boundary *a NUNrounded vowel*.

Comment: Actually this is a known phenomenon in American English. I believe it has been common in Black American English for some time and is currently spreading through White American English. I have not noticed it in British or Australian English yet but I will keep my ears open.

Comment: Or possibly, the sentence was simply uttered by a non-native speaker whose command of the English language is not such that (s)he automatically applies the allomorphic rule to _an_ in unprepared speech.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: The sentence was actually uttered, and then immediately corrected by, me--and I happen to be a native speaker.